# Can not access localhost or 127.0.0.1 server started by vue cli webpack-dev-server

Tags: vue.js, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

I initialized a `vue` project by `vue/cli`, and i do not change any code.After init completion, i run the command to start a development server by `npm run dev`.And the output show the the server running on localhost:8080, but i can not access it neither by `localhost:8080` nor `127.0.0.1:8080`.

I haved tried to uninstall safety software, choose vue/cli@2, check hosts file.

```sh
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\cl>node -v
v10.16.3

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\cl>npm -v
6.9.0

"webpack-dev-server": {
      "version": "2.11.5",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm run serve`. You are not telling vue-cli-service to start a server, only to build locally.